# "Continuity of determinant"

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Im reading a proof of the Implicit function theorem in my class calculus book, and there's one claim that I cannot understand and it not explained in the book.

Denote :

$ F'_{y}\left(x,y\right)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial F^{1}}{\partial y^{1}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial F^{1}}{\partial y^{n}}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial F^{n}}{\partial y^{1}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial F^{n}}{\partial y^{n}}
\end{pmatrix}\left(x,y\right) $

Where $ \left(x,y\right)=\left(x^{1},...x^{m},y^{1},...,y^{n}\right) $,

$ F $ is a function such that $ F:U\to\mathbb{R}^{n} $ where $ U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{m+n} $

And $ F\in C^{(p)}\left(U;\mathbb{R}^{n}\right),p\geq1 $.

Assume that the determinant of $ F'_{y}\left(x,y\right) $ at a point $ (x_0,y_0) $ is not zero.

The claim in the book is that since the determinant at $ (x_0,y_0) $ is not zero, also in some neighborhood of the point $ (x_0,y_0) $ the determinant of the matrix $ F'_y(x,y) $ is not zero.

Why is this true? Im not familier with continuity of determinants

Comment: It follows from Leibniz' formula that the determinant of a matrix is a polynomial in its entries. Here, your entries are continuous functions themselves, so the map $(x,y) \mapsto \det(F'_y(x,y))$ is continuous.

Comment: @Marktmeister Im not familier with Leibnize' formula apparently so I'll ask about the other thing. Why the fact the the entries of my matrix is continuous means that the map $ (x,y) \to \det(F'_y(x,y)) $ is continuous?

Comment: ... this is the part where one uses Leibniz' formula. What formula concerning determinants are you familiar with then?

Comment: @Marktmeister just the recursive definition with the minor

Comment: Then use this definition to prove that the determinant is a polynomial. You can do it by induction, the induction hypothesis tells you that the determinants of the minors are polynomials.

Comment: @Marktmeister if the enteries of the matrix would be polynomials I would totally understand that, but in this case I cant even see how to prove the base of induction. why would multipication of partial derivatives end up to be a polynomials? for example what if the partial derivatives are exponents or maybe trigonometric functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am elaborating on my comments, since you are confusing a few concepts with each other.

Suppose that $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is an $(n \times n)$-matrix. If we identify $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$ with $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ (e.g. by reading the matrix row-wise and then column wise), then the determinant defines a function $\det \colon \mathbb R^{n \times n} = \mathbb R^{n^2} \to \mathbb R$. We show that this function is a polynomial function in the $n^2$ variables by induction on $n$. If we established this claim, then $\det$ is continuous, since it is a polynomial.

For $n = 1$, the matrix $A$ is of the form $(a_{11})$ and $\det(A) = a_{11}$, which is a polynomial in the only variable $a_{11}$. Hence the claim is true for $n = 1$.

Let now $n > 1$. Assume that the claim is already proved for $n-1$. By the Lapace formula, one has
$$\det(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1}  a_{i1}\det(A_{i1}),$$

where $A = (a_{ij})$ and $A_{i1}$ is the matrix obtained from $A$ by deleting the $i$-th row and the $1$-st column. By induction hypothesis, $\det(A_{i1})$ is a polynomial in the entries of $A_{i1}$ for each $i$. Hence, using the above formula for $\det(A)$, one sees that $\det(A)$ is a polynomial, too.

As an example: if $n = 2$, then $\det(A) = a_{11}a_{22} - a_{12}a_{21}$ is a polynomial in the $a_{ij}$!

Now, the map you are considering is the composition of the map

$$U \to \mathbb R^{n \times n}, \ \ \ \ (x,y) \mapsto F'_y(x,y)$$

with the map
$$\mathbb R^{n \times n} \to \mathbb R, \ \ \ \ A \mapsto \det(A).$$

Both these maps are continuous, so their composition $(x,y) \mapsto \det(F'_y(x,y))$ is continuous.